# Half-Life 1 menu crashes on Macbook Air 2012 running Windows 8

Tags: technical-issues, windows-8, half-life

When I try to run Half-Life 1 on my 13" 2012 Macbook Air, which runs Windows 8 natively, it crashes immediately with the following message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: HL.exe
  Application Version:  1.1.1.1
  Application Timestamp:    3fd11900
  Fault Module Name:    opengl32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.2.9200.16384
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5010a91d
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00047f61
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0627
  Additional Information 2: 062795ccd9a7d27934c38fc16044f34d
  Additional Information 3: 20d0
  Additional Information 4: 20d077d1af1dfc006cc3754e64a57308
```

`hl.exe` is running in Windows 7 compatibility mode on the native display at lowest resolution. Running in `-windowed` mode has the same symptom.

My Macbook Air has an Intel HD 4000 graphics card of which I cannot update the driver without bricking my Windows, so I'm stuck on the current driver. I got it working in the past, but I don't remember how I did it. Maybe I replaced the `opengl32.dll` with a modified version, or changed some obscure setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Run in Direct3D mode:

```
hl.exe -d3d
```

Comment: if you found a solution and did post it as an answer, you should also accept the answer, so that *Community* won't bump this thread thinking that it is unanswered

Comment: @Novarg at the time, I could not mark my own answer too soon.